# Changing directory of binaries after compiling

Tags: compiling, directory

I have downloaded a package which includes a makefile. Can I compile the program in the downloaded directory and then move the binaries elsewhere to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but most Makefiles do have a target called `install` that does the job.

Also check if the Makefile has an `uninstall` target, in case you should wish to uninstall the program later.

To facilitate the maintenance, you could use the `checkinstall` program.
(https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can . but why do not put them on the

> /usr/local/bin

or

```
/usr/local/sbin
```

in this case you can use that any where. But if you copy that the directory X, you only can use that ih directory X